# Getting ASPNETDB Username and inserting into detailsview insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a details view on a page used for inserting several user entered fields, but i also want some fields to be automatically entered based on existing user data. I've integrated the ASPNETDB database into my web app and am using that.

I want to be able to pull the currently logged in user and automatically have that information inserted into the *listing user* row when the insert button is used, and preferably keep that field hidden from the users.

Below is my code;

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="dv_insert" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataKeyNames="listingID" DataSourceID="SDS_createlisting" DefaultMode="Insert" 
    Height="50px" Width="125px">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="listingID" HeaderText="listingID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="listingID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="listingtitle" HeaderText="listingtitle" 
            SortExpression="listingtitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="listingdescription" HeaderText="listingdescription" 
            SortExpression="listingdescription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="listinguser" HeaderText="listinguser" 
            SortExpression="listinguser" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="subcategoryname" HeaderText="subcategoryname" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="subcategoryname" Visible="False" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<br />

<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDS_createlisting" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ListingDataConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_listing] WHERE [listingID] = @listingID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_listing] ([listingtitle], [listingdescription], [listinguser], [subcategoryname]) VALUES (@listingtitle, @listingdescription, @listinguser, @subcategoryname)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_listing] WHERE ([subcategoryname] = @subcategoryname)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_listing] SET [listingtitle] = @listingtitle, [listingdescription] = @listingdescription, [listinguser] = @listinguser, [subcategoryname] = @subcategoryname WHERE [listingID] = @listingID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingtitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingdescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="listinguser" Type="String" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="subcategoryname" QueryStringField ="subcategoryname"  />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="subcategoryname" 
            QueryStringField="subcategoryname" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingtitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingdescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="listinguser" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="subcategoryname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="listingID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and the C# component

```
        protected void dv_insert_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Values["listinguser"] = User.Identity.Name;
    }
```